# how to highlight cells that match given criteria

Tags: excel-formula

i have tons of data that i would like to highlight only those cell that fulfill some criteria, said value < 0.100.  Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional formatting](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html). ( More info [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlcondformat03.html), tutorial [here](http://www.timeatlas.com/mos/5_Minute_Tips/General/How_to_use_Conditional_Formatting_to_Highlight_Data/) and  a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3p0fkljYwPY) on YouTube.)

Answer (score 3):

[Conditional Formatting](http://www.automateexcel.com/2009/02/27/excel-conditional-formatting/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct, but I would add that if I recall correctly you can have unlimited conditional formatting on the same cell(s) in Excel 2007, but only three conditions pre-Excel 2007.

Comment: Up to three COnditional formats are allowed up to Excel 2003, and from Excel 2007 onwards this limit was removed.
http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2005/09/26/474258.aspx

Comment: From what I know, You can have up to 3 conditions per cell in Excel 2003 and earlier ones. If You want more - You need to use VBA.